# Asp.Net MapPageRoute effects all links in project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.Net Mvc 5.0 project, my RouteCollection in the following codes.
The problem using `MapPageRoute`for static pages, it effects all form posts in  project.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("staticpage", "mystatic", "~/StaticPages/index.html");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

For example if i try to sign out it goes to `/mystatic?action=Index&controller=Home` but should go `"/"`

```
<form action="/Account/SignOut" method="post">        
<input type="submit" class="login-button btn-signout" value="" />  
</form>
```

AccountController:

```
  public ActionResult SignOut()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();  
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Why MapPageRoute conflict with other links ?